# "bad quoted string" in go generate

Tags: go

I'm trying to insert a file as a variable in a go file using `go generate` but it fails with `bad quoted string`, the issue is that I can run this in a shell without issue:

```
//go:generate echo "var baseConfigProduction = \`" && cat base-production.json && echo "\`"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Show the exact `go:generate` comment please.

Comment: Updated with the actual line.

Comment: Go generate isn't executing a shell. If you want a shell you need to execute one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go generate only works by calling *one* command. If you want to call several, you either put them into a BASH script, or do something like this:

```
//go:generate echo var baseConfigProduction = `
//go:generate cat base-production.json
//go:generate echo `
```

But AFAIK, the order of evaluation for several `go:generate` commands is undefined, so you can't really count on that, so I would recommend sticking to BASH scripts.

**EDIT:** Another possibility:

```
//go:generate sh -c "echo var baseConfigProduction = \\`$DOLLAR(cat base-production.json)\\`"
```